How to control the cleaning of the mdc in Spring-Sleuth?
There is a core project that uses Spring-Sleuth. And there is logic in the AspectJ aspect, where some logic is asynchronously executed in CompletableFuture, including logging via Logback. And judging by the debugging, even before the CompletableFuture code is executed, the mdc is cleared in the TraceRunnable spring-sleuth class and nothing is output as a result. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?
